# iOS: IBOutlet nil in Xcode 6

Tags: ios, xcode, ios8, iboutlet, xcode6

Using iOS 8 and Xcode 6. I embedded a UIWebView in a controller using a storyboard, and hooked everything up. When I run it, though, the webView is coming up nil. Any thoughts?

[image]

Comment: How are you initializing your view controller?

Comment: i am having the same issue when instantiating a view controller from a storyboard.

Comment: same issue here. My web view is always nil when the view controller loads

Comment: Am also having the same problem. My others viewcontrollers were fine, now any new view controller created within SB have all nil IBOutlets

Comment: Modify weak @property for webView.

Comment: Same issue. On Simulator all works fine, on device some of the outlets are nil

Answer (score 1):

What helped me is [this answer #1 here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26990124/1898917).

1. Clean project
2. Close XCode
3. Delete all contents of ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/
4. Restart MacOs

Exactly in this order.

Answer (score 0):

Modify weak @property for webView.

Comment: changing to strong doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this problem myself and finally found a solution:
At some point Apple changed the way View Controllers are linked with their xib files. Xcode no longer automatically matches, for example, ViewController.swift and ViewController.xib. Instead you must explicitly specify a nib name in your code. Try calling:

```
NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("ViewController", owner: self, options: nil)
```

or, in Objective C:

```
[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ViewController" owner:self options:nil];
```

in your VC's initializer, before you use any IBOutlets (replacing "ViewController" with the name of your View Controller). This is what finally worked for me (in Swift).

See also:

[Are view controllers with nib files broken in ios 8 beta 5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25149604/are-view-controllers-with-nib-files-broken-in-ios-8-beta-5/25152545#25152545)

[Swift proper way to load xib file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26539849/swift-proper-way-to-load-xib-file)