# IBoutlets nil in xCode 6 Beta 5 when instantiate a ViewController from a Storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller, swift

I switched from xCode 6 Beta 4 to xCode 6 Beta 5 and all the `IBOutlet` of my class are now nil despite my ViewController is successfully instantiated.

I've got a ViewController in my `Storybord` which inherits from `ImagePickerViewController` with an identifier.

In Swift code, I instantiate my ViewController this way:

```
let viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(ImagePickerViewControllerIdentifier) as ImagePickerViewController
```

The viewController is found and instantiated but the `IBOutlet` inside are set to `nil` instead of being linked to the elements contained into my ViewController.

I found this answer to a similar problem:

[Are view controllers with nib files broken in ios 8 beta 5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25149604/are-view-controllers-with-nib-files-broken-in-ios-8-beta-5/25152545#25152545)

When I tried the matt's solution, I've got a crash when I launched my app:

> Unknown class _TtC7MyProject25ImagePickerViewController in Interface
>   Builder file.

I think it's due to this tricks:

```
@objc(ImagePickerViewController) class ImagePickerViewController : UIViewController
```

Any suggestion to avoid the crash ?

Thanks !

**Edit:** After some tests, I found the bug. I don't need anymore to use the tricks pasted above. It came from the iOS Simulator. I deleted the app and installed once again and it works well.