# Custom Input view from Storyboard? - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, inputview

A few months back there was a [question posted regarding a custom input view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26601293/custom-input-view-in-swift), it was answered by David Berry

The answer works perfectly but I've been trying to get the same to work with a storyboard rather then a nib.

What is the equivalent code to load this with a storyboard in place of a nib?

```
   if let objects = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("InputView", owner: self, options: nil) {
        myInputView = objects[0] as UIView
    }
```

Comment: Why don't you add the custom input view to the view controller in the storyboard (no need for any code)? You can hide it (or position it off screen) until you want it to appear.