# load xib file into a container

Tags: ios, swift

I have my sidebar placed in a xib file with a UIViewController
now I need to load this xib file into a container.
how do I do this?

please give me a swift code example
thanx in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use sidebar in your app use `swrevealviewcontroller`

It is third party control.but easy to use and implement.

[swrevealviewcontroller](http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-sidebar-navigation-menu/)

May be it will help you.

Comment: yes I checked that out, but I just want to know how this works, is there any way to add xib to container?

Comment: What are you using? stroyboard or xib?

Comment: my container is in storyboard, but I want to add the sidebar to each page. so it's best to have the sidebar in a different xib file and add the programatically , right?

Comment: What r u using swift or objective c?

Comment: I dont have idea in swift using xib.go through this link it may help you.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26539849/swift-proper-way-to-load-xib-file